# difference between constructor and class in javascript

Tags: javascript, class, object

what is the const halley=... referring to?Is it storing the new created object?or is itself a new object?and what does the Dog after the new keyword  means?Class or constructor?

```
class Dog {
 constructor(name) {
   this.name = name;
   this.behavior = 0;
 } 
}

const halley = new Dog('Halley'); // Create new Dog instance
console.log(halley.name);
```

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)? `halley` is an instance of `Dog`; an instance is a newly created object. Not sure what the difference to “itself a new object” would be.

Comment: https://javascript.info/class

Comment: `const myDog = new Dog('Halley');` .. `console.log(myDog.name);`

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, a *constructor function* is a function designed for use with the `new` keyword to create instances of a type of object. Typically you would assign something to its `prototype` property to define properties that would be inherited by the instance.

The `class` keyword is a newish feature that allows the creation of a constructor function and its associated prototype using syntax which looks more like traditional OO syntax in other programming languages.

The value assigned to `Dog` is both a class and a constructor function.

Answer (score 0):

This part define the class. A class is like a recipe to make objects. A constructor is a method of a class that define how to create new instances (objects):

```
class Dog {
 constructor(name) {
   this.name = name;
   this.behavior = 0;
 } 
}
```

This part create an instance (object) of the class Dog:

```
const halley = new Dog('Halley');
```

Comment: That was so useful

Comment: we are passing 'Halley' as an argument to Dog class or the Dog constructor?

Comment: @MisterJojo No, `halley` is the instance, but the string `"Halley"` is being passed to the `Dog` constructor function… or the `Dog` class. `halley` is also never an argument.

Comment: @GitaNeupane neither of the two. **argument value* `"haley"`became an instance variable value . it is completely stupid to have given the same word for the instance name and the argument value to build a code example